# Laravel Eloquent Model Dependency Injection with preformated Id to find()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Normally we can simplify finding User by id logic in controller by injecting the `User` Class in parameter. Like this:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
   public function show(User $id)
   {
      return $user;
   }
}
```

But now I must treat the Id to find like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class UserController extends Controller
{
   public function show(User $id)
   {
      $preformattedId = '98'.$id;

      $user = User::find($preformattedId );

      return $user;
   }
}
```

My basic question is: how I can achieved that same trick to my preformatted id in below code like the above code?

Note: I have to use the Id this way because i work with legacy database that actually adding that '98' prefix in every Id, despite that we only use characters after that prefix.

Comment: Why your are using value prefix instead of table prefix??? In laravel you can simply `encrypt` and `decrypt` id.

Comment: As I noted above, i must use that format because of legacy scheme in db. And for the sake of clarity i want to send the id without that prefix. If it is create or save method maybe i can do something in ```public static function boot()``` in model, but after long hours of searching and my lack of knowledge about OOP in laravel, i can't hold to search anymore. :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use Inversion of Control by using explicit binding on your router.

In your `RouteServiceProvider`

```php
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::bind('user', function ($value) {
        return User::find('98'.$value);
    });
}
```

Or in your `User` model

```php
/**
 * Retrieve the model for a bound value.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @param  string|null  $field
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
 */
public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null)
{
    return $this->find('98'.$value);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#explicit-binding

Answer (score 0):

You can share your route file ?

But if your file is

```php
Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@show');
```

When you use

```php
class UserController extends Controller
{
   public function show(User $id)
   {
      // you don't need use find function, it is make automatic by laravel
      $user = $id;
      return $user;
   }
}
```

if you want to get id, just remove `User` type inside `show` parameter

```php
class UserController extends Controller
{
   public function show($id)
   {
      $preformattedId = '98'.$id;

      $user = User::find($preformattedId );

      return $user;
   }
}
```